# K-Means clustering in R error NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataset that I have created in R. It is structured as follows:
[image]

I am trying to cluster the observations using k-means. However, I get the following error message:

```r
> cl <- kmeans(sample, 3)

Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

What does this mean? Am I prepocessing the data incorrectly? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Your picture shows a mixture of character (ID, Genre) and numeric data. The kmeans function only works with numeric data. What does `str(samples)` show?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of `kmeans` (pass `?kmeans` in the console to see it), it is stipulated that the argument `x` has to be:

> numeric matrix of data, or an object that can be coerced to such a matrix (such as a numeric vector or a data frame with all numeric columns).

Here, you have the first row that is preventing to be used for `kmeans`. Basically, I believed that your first row is supposed to be your `colnames`.

Moreover, you can't make clustering with your second columns `genre` as it is character and I believed that the first column does not have to be used also, am I right ?

So, if your dataset is called `samples`, try to do:

```r
colnames(samples) <- samples[1,]
samples_cluster <- samples[-1,3:ncol(samples)]
cl <- kmeans(samples_cluster,3)
```

Does it answer your question ?

If not, can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset in order we can verify the dataframe for `kmeans` clustering. To do this, please see: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)